# Install an ELK stack on OpenShift

Tags: logging, kubernetes, openshift, elastic-stack

I'm new to OpenShift (I've been using marathon/DCOS before) and I'm willing to install an Elastic stack on it, all the tutorials I've found online are describing it as a "complicated task"

So here's my question, Am I looking for something impossible/not recommended?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

It's so much of a complicated task but it really depends on your experience. OpenShift essentially runs on top of Kubernetes and there are plenty of tutorials on how to install ELK or Elasticsearch on Kubernetes.

Perhaps there's a little less information about OpenShift specifically, but you can start with an EFK stack which is Elasticsearch, Fluentd and Kibana documented [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#deploying-the-efk-stack). Here's another walkthrough to set up [ELK specifically on OpenShift](https://github.com/lbischof/openshift3-elk). And here's another one form the [Kubernetes Main Site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/)

Hope it helps!